# Checking two ranges in different workbooks (run time error 424)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check whether the values in `workbook1-sheet1-A` are matched in `workbook2-sheet2-E`. If there is a match `workbook1-sheet1-Y` receives a `'x'`.

This is the code I have so far and gives me `Run time error 424 - Object required` error on the if loop.

```
Sub Check()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

endRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wkbSLA = ("F:\Workbook2")

For i = 2 To endRow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = wkbSLA.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2:E575").Value Then
        Range("Y" & i) = "x"
    End If
Next i

'
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What line is the exception being thrown on?  Also, is `wkbSLA' already open?

Comment: @Trisped, wkbSLA doesn't need to be opened, it's a dump file. It's being thrown at `If Cells(i, 1).Value = wkbSLA.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2:E575").Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure your code is doing everything you expect it to it, make sure you qualify your objects with variables.

Also, you cannot use the `.Value` property on multi-cell range. That is probably where your error is hitting. A better way to approach this is with the `.Find` method.

If you write the code something like this, it should work for you ... though you may need to tweak it a bit to meet your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Check()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wkb1 as Workbook, wkb2 as workbook
Set wkb1 = Workbooks("workbook1")
Set wkb2 = Workbooks("F:\Workbook2") 
' -> do you need Workbooks.Open("F:\Workbook2") here? 
' Seems you may if the workbook you want to access is closed

Dim wks1 as Worksheet, wks2 as Worksheet
Set wks1 = wkb1.Sheets(1) 'may need to change this reference for your needs
Set wks2 = wkb2.Sheets("Sheet2")

With wks1

    Dim endRow as Long
    endRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i as Long
    For i = 2 To endRow

        Dim rng as Range
        Set rng = wks2.Range("E2:E575").Find .Cells(i,1).Value lookat:=xlWhole

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then .Range("Y" & i) = "x"

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible you're missing something in the `IF`? Do you need to open the workbook to be able to search the content?

Comment: @t.thielemans -> I can't tell if the workbook is open or not. I left that comment in the code. That's for the OP to distinguish. AFAIK, a workbook has to be opened to search through, at least in VBA. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I was asking you ;) but I receive an error on `If wks2.Range("E2:E575").Find cells(i,1).Value lookat:=xlWhole Then .Range("Y" & i) = "x"`, as if something were missing

Comment: @t.thielemans -> something was missing. In fact 2 things. 1) the error trap, 2) the `.` in front `Cells`. Both are updated in my edit :)

Comment: @t.thielemans -> can you verify if you need the workbook open to search the content. I am almost positive you do.